# Merge Json array date based

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, grouping

I can't find a solution for this :

i want to **group** json array based on one column (**date**) and sort it with **Javascript** / **Jquery** ? :

I have been trying finding a solution but i can't figure out.

```
[
    {
    "date" : "2010-01-01",
    "price" : 30
    },
    {
    "date" : "2010-02-01",
    "price" : 40
    },
    {
    "date" : "2010-03-01",
    "price" : 50
    },
    {
    "date" : "2010-01-01",
    "price2" : 45
    },
    {
    "date" : "2010-05-01",
    "price2" : 40
    },
    {
    "date" : "2010-10-01",
    "price2" : 50
    }
]
```

I want this :

```
[
    {
        "date" : "2010-01-01",
        "price" : 30,
        "price2" : 45
    },
    {
        "date" : "2010-02-01",
        "price" : 40,
        "price2" : null
    },
    {
        "date" : "2010-03-01",
        "price" : 50,
        "price2" : null
    },
    {
        "date" : "2010-05-01",
        "price" : null,
        "price2" : 40
    },
    {
        "date" : "2010-10-01",
        "price" : null
        "price2" : 50
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between the first and second price? Are you sure you will you never have more than two prices for the same date? If you answered "no" to any of those questions, I suggest using a `prices` array rather than multiple `priceN` fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use `sort()` method to sort elements by date and then you can use `forEach()` to group elements by date.

```js
var data = [{"date":"2010-01-01","price":30},{"date":"2010-02-01","price":40},{"date":"2010-03-01","price":50},{"date":"2010-01-01","price2":45},{"date":"2010-05-01","price2":40},{"date":"2010-10-01","price2":50}]
data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))

var result = []
data.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.date]) {
    this[e.date] = {date: e.date, price: null, price2: null}
    result.push(this[e.date])
  }
  this[e.date] = Object.assign(this[e.date], e)
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var prices = [{"date":"2010-01-01","price":30},{"date":"2010-02-01","price":40},{"date":"2010-03-01","price":50},{"date":"2010-01-01","price2":45},{"date":"2010-05-01","price2":40},{"date":"2010-10-01","price2":50}];

var prices2 = prices.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  var dateElement = acc.find(function(element) {
    return val.date === element.date;
  });

  if (!dateElement) {
    dateElement = {
      date: val.date,
      price: null,
      price2: null,
    };
    acc.push(dateElement);
  }
  dateElement.price = dateElement.price || val.price;
  dateElement.price2 = dateElement.price2 || val.price2;

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(prices2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Array.reduce` and `Array.map` to loop and `Object.assign` to merge

```js
var data = [{"date":"2010-01-01","price":30},{"date":"2010-02-01","price":40},{"date":"2010-03-01","price":50},{"date":"2010-01-01","price2":45},{"date":"2010-05-01","price2":40},{"date":"2010-10-01","price2":50}]

var result = data.reduce((p, c) => 
  (p[c.date] = Object.assign({},{price: null, price2:null}, p[c.date], c)) && p
  , {});

var final = Object.keys(result).map(x=>result[x])

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object as reference to the same date.

```js
var data = [{ date: "2010-01-01", price: 30 }, { date: "2010-02-01", price: 40 }, { date: "2010-03-01", price: 50 }, { date: "2010-01-01", price2: 45 }, { date: "2010-05-01", price2: 40 }, { date: "2010-10-01", price2: 50 }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (hash) {
    return function (o) {
        if (!hash[o.date]) {
            hash[o.date] = { date: o.date, price: null, price2: null };
            grouped.push(hash[o.date]);
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k === 'date') {
                return;
            }
            hash[o.date][k] = o[k];
        });
    };
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```