# Merge results from json arrays by date

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, merge

I am trying to merge the results from a given JSON in jQuery.
Currently, I have been trying to use the snippets here: [Merge Json array date based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510698/merge-json-array-date-based) but I have not had any luck achieving the end result I need.

Current results:

```
[
  {
    "searches": "37",
    "views": "0",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2019-12-31"
  },
  {
    "searches": "0",
    "views": "6",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2019-12-31"
  },
  {
    "searches": "68",
    "views": "0",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  },
  {
    "searches": "0",
    "views": "6",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  }
]
```

Results to achieve:

```
[
  {
    "searches": "37",
    "views": "6",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2019-12-31"
  },
  {
    "searches": "68",
    "views": "6",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  },
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can try this :    let arrayOfJSONObjects=[{your array values here }]



for(let i=0;i<arrayOfJSONObjects.length;i++){
if(item.date == item[i-1].date){
item.date=item[i-1].date
item[i].searches=item[i-1].searches
item.views=item[i-1].views
item.leads=item[i-1].leads
item.fliers=item[i-1].fliers
item.website=item[i-1].website
item.calls=item[i-1].calls
item.shares=item[i-1].shares

arrayOfJSONObjects.splice( i-1 , 1);

}

}

Comment: @user3189162 Why not just put that in an answer?

Comment: actually, I didn't test the answer it's a quick response

Comment: you can try this edited one :    let arrayOfJSONObjects=[{your array values here }]



for(let i=0;i<arrayOfJSONObjects.length;i++){
if(item[i].date == item[i-1].date){
item[i].date=item[i-1].date
item[i].searches=item[i-1].searches
item[i].views=item[i-1].views
item[i].leads=item[i-1].leads
item[i].fliers=item[i-1].fliers
item[i].website=item[i-1].website
item[i].calls=item[i-1].calls
item[i].shares=item[i-1].shares

arrayOfJSONObjects.splice( i-1 , 1);

}

}

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I unfortunately could not get this work right. Maybe im doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made with reduce function

```
let merged_arr = arr.reduce((acc, cur, index, arr)=>{

    let new_acc = [];

    if(index === 1){

        new_acc.push(acc);

        if(acc.date === cur.date){

            new_acc.map((o)=>{
                o.searches = +o.searches + +cur.searches;
                o.views = +o.views + +cur.views;
                o.leads = +o.leads + +cur.leads;
                o.fliers = +o.fliers + +cur.fliers;
                o.website = +o.website + +cur.website;
                o.calls = +o.calls + +cur.calls;
                o.shares = +o.shares + +cur.shares;
            });

        } else {
            new_acc.push(cur)
        }

    } else {

        new_acc = acc;

        if( new_acc.some( (o)=>{ return Object.values(o).includes(cur.date) } ) ){

            new_acc.map((o)=>{ 
                if(o.date === cur.date){
                    o.searches = +o.searches + +cur.searches;
                    o.views = +o.views + +cur.views;
                    o.leads = +o.leads + +cur.leads;
                    o.fliers = +o.fliers + +cur.fliers;
                    o.website = +o.website + +cur.website;
                    o.calls = +o.calls + +cur.calls;
                    o.shares = +o.shares + +cur.shares;
                }
            });

        } else {
            new_acc.push(cur);
        }

    }

    return new_acc;

});
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3fGy.png)

Or like this:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "searches": "37",
    "views": "0",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2019-12-31"
  },
  {
    "searches": "0",
    "views": "6",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2019-12-31"
  },
  {
    "searches": "68",
    "views": "0",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  },
  {
    "searches": "0",
    "views": "6",
    "leads": "0",
    "fliers": "0",
    "website": "0",
    "calls": "0",
    "shares": "0",
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  }
];

let merged_arr = arr.reduce((acc, cur, index, arr)=>{

    let new_acc = [];

    if(index === 1){

        new_acc.push(acc);

        if(acc.date === cur.date){

            new_acc.map((o)=>{
                o.searches = (+o.searches + +cur.searches).toString();
                o.views = (+o.views + +cur.views).toString();
                o.leads = (+o.leads + +cur.leads).toString();
                o.fliers = (+o.fliers + +cur.fliers).toString();
                o.website = (+o.website + +cur.website).toString();
                o.calls = (+o.calls + +cur.calls).toString();
                o.shares = (+o.shares + +cur.shares).toString();
            });

        } else {
            new_acc.push(cur)
        }

    } else {

        new_acc = acc;

        if( new_acc.some( (o)=>{ return Object.values(o).includes(cur.date) } ) ){

            new_acc.map((o)=>{ 
                if(o.date === cur.date){
                    o.searches = (+o.searches + +cur.searches).toString();
                    o.views = (+o.views + +cur.views).toString();
                    o.leads = (+o.leads + +cur.leads).toString();
                    o.fliers = (+o.fliers + +cur.fliers).toString();
                    o.website = (+o.website + +cur.website).toString();
                    o.calls = (+o.calls + +cur.calls).toString();
                    o.shares = (+o.shares + +cur.shares).toString();
                }
            });

        } else {
            new_acc.push(cur);
        }

    }

    return new_acc;

});

console.log('merged_arr: ', merged_arr);
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This is definitely working. However, I noticed one interesting thing, not sure why it does this, but some of the array values are encased in quotation marks while everything else isn't. Image for what I'm talking about: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/677606397042753570/696040709525995551/Annotation_2020-04-04_115648.png

Comment: @Crum OK, the question is, how would you like to be? would you like to be all in quation mark? or would you like that the numbers to be in Intiger(like now) and the date value to be in Date() format? If would you like that the numbers to be converted back into quotation mark, than you need to add for every value this line: example: o.views = (+o.views + +cur.views).toString(); . If you dont understand then write to me and I will change the code for you!

Comment: @Crum OK, I added new code to my answer, for your quotaion mark problem :)